# Using subqueries to sum an associated model's column returns the same amount for all parents

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, performance

Given the models `User` and `Invoice`, a user has many invoices and an invoice belongs to a user.

Invoices have a `status` and `amount_cents` columns.

I need to write a query that gets all the User columns but also adds the following columns:

- a `total_paid` alias column that sums the `amount_cents` of all `paid` invoices for each User
- a `total_unpaid` alias column that sums the `amount_cents` of all `unpaid` invoices for each User

I'm kind of lost as to what the correct structure is when using multiple subqueries that I assign an alias to, but I've come up with something pretty basic for the first part of the task:

```
select users.*, (SELECT SUM(amount_cents) FROM invoices) as total_paid from users
join invoices on users.id = invoices.user_id
where invoices.status = 'paid'
group by users.id
```

I'm not sure if I should be writing the query from the parent or children side (I suppose from the parent (User) side since all the data I need is in the users column) but the above query seems to be returning the same amounts in the `total_paid` column for all the different users instead of the right amount for each user.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using subqueries as follows:

```
Select users.id,
       (Select Sum(amount_cents) 
        From invoices Where status = 'paid' And user_id=users.id) As total_paid,
       (Select Sum(amount_cents)
        From invoices Where status = 'unpaid' And user_id=users.id) As total_unpaid
From users
Group by users.id
```

Answer (score 2):

The statement (SELECT SUM(amount_cents) FROM invoices) returns the total amount for all the users, which is different from the amount per user that you want :

**Solution with a LATERAL JOIN :**

```
select u.*
    , paid.total as total_paid
    , unpaid.total as total_unpaid
 FROM users AS u
 LEFT JOIN LATERAL
    ( SELECT sum(amount_cents) AS total
        FROM invoices
       WHERE user_id = u.id
         AND status = 'paid'
    ) AS paid
   ON True
 LEFT JOIN LATERAL
    ( SELECT sum(amount_cents) AS total
        FROM invoices
       WHERE user_id = u.id
         AND status = 'unpaid'
    ) AS unpaid
   ON True
```

**Solution with a JOIN & window function :**

```
SELECT u.*
     , t.total_paid
     , t.total_unpaid
  FROM users AS u
 INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id)
     , user_id
     , sum(amount_cents) FILTER (WHERE status = 'paid') OVER (PARTITION BY user_id  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS total_paid
     , sum(amount_cents) FILTER (WHERE status = 'unpaid') OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS total_unpaid
  FROM invoices
 ORDER BY u.user_id
) AS t
ON u.id = t.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks. Even though I chose another answer as the accepted answer because it was more simple and easier to transform to ActiveRecord statements, your solutions helped me understand both concepts. The window function solution was returning a syntax error though, which I could not fix.

Answer (score 2):

You can use scalar subqueries

```sql
select u.*, 
       (select sum(amount_cents) from invoices where user_id = u.id and status = 'paid') total_paid,
       (select sum(amount_cents) from invoices where user_id = u.id and status = 'unpaid') total_unpaid
from users u;
```

or a lateral join which might be a bit more efficient.

```sql
select u.*, l.*
from users u
left join lateral 
(
  select sum(amount_cents) filter (where status = 'paid') total_paid,
         sum(amount_cents) filter (where status = 'unpaid') total_unpaid
  from invoices where user_id = u.id
) l on true;
```

If however `users.id` is primary key (which is probably the case) then things can be simplified to

```sql
select u.*, 
       sum(i.amount_cents) filter (where i.status = 'paid') total_paid,
       sum(i.amount_cents) filter (where i.status = 'unpaid') total_unpaid 
from users u
left outer join invoices i on u.id = i.user_id
group by u.id;
```

Comment: I think the last solution is probably the cleanest solution although I might change `total_unpaid` to `filter (where i.status <> 'paid')` since the status for what is unpaid was not specified in the question.

Comment: @engineersmnky Fair point.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use Outer Joins

```
  users_table = User.arel_table
  paid_invoices_table = Arel::Table.new(Invoice.arel_table.name, as: 'paid_invoices')
  unpaid_invoices_table = Arel::Table.new(Invoice.arel_table.name, as: 'unpaid_invoices')

  paid_join = Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin.new(
    paid_invoices_table,
    Arel::Nodes::On.new(
      users_table[:id].eq(paid_invoices_table[:user_id])
        .and(paid_invoices_table[:status].eq('paid'))
    )
  )

  unpaid_join = Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin.new(
    unpaid_invoices_table,
    Arel::Nodes::On.new(
      users_table[:id].eq(unpaid_invoices_table[:user_id])
        .and(unpaid_invoices_table[:status].not_eq('paid'))
    )
  )

  User.joins(paid_join,unpaid_join)
    .select(
       User.arel_table[Arel.star],
       paid_invoices_table[:amount_cents].sum.as('total_paid'), 
       unpaid_invoices_table[:amount_cents].sum.as('total_unpaid'))   
    .group(:id)
```

Resulting Query:

```
SELECT 
  users.*,
  SUM(paid_invoices.amount_cents) AS total_paid,
  SUM(unpaid_invoices.amount_cents) AS total_unpaid
FROM 
  users 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN invoices AS paid_invoices ON users.id = paid_invoices.user_id
    AND paid_invoices.status = 'paid' 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN invoices AS unpaid_invoices ON users.id = unpaid_invoices.user_id
    AND unpaid_invoices.status <> 'paid'
GROUP BY 
  users.id
```